# create a popover segue clicking a view inside a tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

So i'm trying to create a popover that appears when clicking a view inside a tableview cell.  Here's what I've tried so far.
This is what I have inside my customcell:

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var openingHoursView: CustomView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("openingHoursTap:"))
    openingHoursView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
}
```

This is what i have inside my view controller:

```
    else if segue.identifier == "openingHours" {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController
        var controller = vc.popoverPresentationController
        if controller != nil {
            controller?.delegate = self
        }
    }

@IBAction func openingHoursTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("openingHours", sender: self)
}


func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}
```

identifier is correct.  The anchor is to the tableview for the segue. I've never actually created a tappable view before, but did do the same thing with a button just and it worked fine. No errors, app just crashes when clicking the view.

I'm guessing it could be something to do with me not adding it into cellForRowAtIndexPath for the individual cell.  How would this be done with a view if i cant addTarget?

Comment: you are calling `openingHoursTap:`  in your table cell, but your actual implementation of `openingHoursTap:` is in your view controller right?

Comment: correct, trying to implement it inside my tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `openingHoursTap:` in your table view cell but your actual implementation is in your view controller. That's why it crashes. So the correct way to do this is add the tap gesture recogniser in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexpath:` in your view controller.

Example:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("openingHoursTap:"))

    cell.openingHoursView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}`

Comment: Ahh yeah makes sense, couldn't figure out how to add it to cellForRowAtIndexpath.  Thanks